# How do I persuade this jQuery button click event to submit the correct form [in Safari]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

In the jQuery 'ready' block, I have:

```
// bind print work order button to form submit
$('#print_work_order_button').click(function(){
    $('#print_work_order_form').submit();
});
```

... and in the HTML (ignore the variable replacement code... it's working fine):

```
<form id="print_work_order_form" method="post" action="<TMPL_VAR NAME=SCRIPT_NAME>" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="printWorkOrder">
<input type="hidden" name="case_id" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=ID>">
<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=SESSION_ID>">
</form>
```

However, when I click the following button:

```
<input id="print_work_order_button" type="button" value="Print Work Order">
```

... a different form gets submitted.  The form that gets submitted is case_form, which is being validated in the jQuery ready block as well:

```
// validate main form
$('#case_form').validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        phone: {
            phoneUS: true,
            required: true
        }
        [more rules etc...]
    },
    messages: {
        phone: '555-555-5555',
        client_group_id: 'X',
        description: 'X',
        backup_data: 'X',
        first_name: 'X',
        last_name: 'X',
        email: 'X'
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                ? 'You missed 1 field.'
                : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.';
            displayMessage(message);
        } 
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        displayMessage('Saving and syncing with Remedy... we appreciate your patience.', '1');
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

My only recent change was moving this validate routine into the 'ready' block, so I think that's the problem but I don't know how to fix.  I need validate in the 'ready' block in order for that to work... so how do I fix my other, unrelated form submit?

NOTE: oddly, this appears to be a Safari-only bug.  I cannot reproduce in any other browser yet.

Comment: where is #case_form in this senerio

Comment: What other "click" handlers do you set up for buttons, and how do you set it up?  It's possible that there's one or more additional "click" handlers bound to your button.

Comment: No forms nested, one click event per button... good questions though!

Comment: ok... no forms nested within each other but there are div tags interfering with the parsing of the forms... so it's an issue Safari is having with parsing a closing </form> tag which is nested improperly among divs, relative to the open <form> tag.

Comment: The question really is now: what solution would you recommend to get around weird <form> nestings among divs?  I want to free my input elements from having to be nested within the forms they belong to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a submit button instead?

```
<form id="print_work_order_form" method="post" action="<TMPL_VAR NAME=SCRIPT_NAME>" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="printWorkOrder">
<input type="hidden" name="case_id" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=ID>">
<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=SESSION_ID>">

<input id="print_work_order_button" type="submit" value="Print Work Order">

</form>

 $('#print_work_order_form').submit();
```

or

```
$('#print_work_order_form').validate();
```

Comment: Well, the reason I am using a 'button' type instead of 'submit' type is because the button does not live inside the form.  I changed it to 'submit' anyway, but it did not work.

Comment: @Marcus - Can you make it live in the form?

Comment: Good idea... just tried it though... still broken in Safari.  What is it about Safari?  Driving me nuts.

Comment: @Marcus - does it come up with any errors or warnings? Do you think you can make a http://jsfiddle.net/ that has the error so we can see?

Comment: My final solution was to give in and make the buttons live inside the forms and be actual submit type buttons.  I was reluctant to do this before because forms always caused line breaks, but now I know to use 'display: inline;' CSS style for the form.  Thanks to everyone who helped steer me in the right direction... be careful with jQuery validate, it does odd things to form submits, anyone with great wisdom feel free to add further answers to this question!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly some browsers will treat any of the following HTML input types as "submit" buttons when clicked.

```
<input type="image" ... />
<input type="submit" ... />
```

My guess would then be that your `<input id="print_work_order_button" type="button" value="Print Work Order">` is actually living inside the form that is being accidentally submitted.

---

If I may make a suggestion it would be to NOT define `click` handlers for a form's buttons, but rather to override a form's `submit` handler so that no matter how a form is submitted (e.g., by clicking an image, clicking submit or hitting enter), your code will always get called.

Comment: Only the first two. Not type="button"

Comment: The button does not live inside any form.  I really only do want the form submitted when the button is clicked...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing more of your code, but it should work if you change your binding to `preventDefault()`:

```
// bind print work order button to form submit
$('#print_work_order_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#print_work_order_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: This did not seem to work.  A reminder that I am only seeing this in Safari.